# Pyshark spawns command-line windows when packaged with cx_freeze. How can I prevent that?

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pyshark

I'm using cx_freeze to package my python application into an EXE file. I've managed to hide the python console window with the option `base = 'Win32GUI'`, but for some reason when I use the pyshark module it spawns two additional command prompts: one for tshark and another for dumpcap.

This does not happen when I execute the python file directly, the windows only appears when I run the EXE file.

Is there a way to hide them or make them not appear in the first place?